# Estimate the time it will take to train a chatbot pointing to its total accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot

I'm learning how to build a chatbot with Tensorflow and Python, and I built a chatbot that is being trained through a JSON file with that structure:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "patterns": [
                "Hi",
                "How are you",
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Hello, my name is Jonh!",
                "Good to see you again!"
            ],
            "tag": "greeting"
        }
        (...)
      ]
}
```

From what I realized, the epoch represents the number of times that the JSON file will be read by the algorithm to train the chatbot, so basically when the JSON file has too much information, there's a need to increase the Epoch, to increase the chatbot accuracy.

```
self.model.fit(self.training, self.output, n_epoch=10000, batch_size=32, show_metric=True)
```

I would like to know a simple way to increase the epoch automatically based on the amount of information in the JSON file.

Comment: If it's usefull or not in this case is beyond my knowledge with tensorflow but in general, you could check the JSON file size or the amount of entries in it (depending on what seems more logical in your case) and adjust the n_epoch.

Comment: There is a tutorial on Chatbot with [Tensorflow transformer](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/05/transformer-chatbot-tutorial-with-tensorflow-2.html). Take a look at this tutorial. Thanks!